# Obter coordenadas do rato em relação a um elemento específico

Tags: javascript

Criei um gráfico em que movo uns objetos com o rato. Queria obter as reais coordenadas definidas no gráfico. Estou a obter so as posições x e y das coordenadas da janela. No meu eixo defino o maximo e o minimo de x, e caso o objeto esteja no meio do eixo, obter por exemplo a metade do maximo. O eixo x tem de tamanho 400px. Como posso obter as coordenadas reais?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No evento `mousemove` de determinado elemento, você obtém as coordenadas do cursor **em relação à janela** com as propriedades `clientX` e `clientY` do evento:

```
elemento.onmousemove = function(e) {
    // coordenadas em e.clientX e e.clientY
}
```

Para calcular a coordenada relativa ao elemento em si, ou a algum outro, primeiro você precisa descobrir a posição do elemento na janela. Isso você consegue com o [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) do elemento:

```
var boxDoElemento = elemento.getBoundingClientRect();
alert(boxDoElemento.left); // posição x
alert(boxDoElemento.top);  // posição y
```

Se não houver rolamento da página, basta subtrair a posição do elemento da posição do cursor do mouse para obter a posição relativa. Se houver rolamento, é preciso descontá-lo.

Juntando tudo para conseguir o que você quer, considerando um elemento numa posição arbitrária da tela (o de borda vermelha):

```js
var elemento = document.querySelector('#meuElemento');
var boxDoElemento = elemento.getBoundingClientRect();

elemento.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var rolamentoX = document.body.scrollLeft;
    var rolamentoY = document.body.scrollTop;
    var posX = e.clientX - boxDoElemento.left + rolamentoX;
    var posY = e.clientY - boxDoElemento.top + rolamentoY;
    elemento.innerHTML = posX + ', ' + posY;
}
```

```css
#meuElemento {
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="meuElemento">passe o mouse aqui dentro</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, tenho aqui o meu exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/7gsn30xr/7/ Consigo obter os valores os objetos, mas nao consigo obter os dos grqfico.

Comment: Seu SVG ocupa a tela toda e está na posição `0,0`, mas os eixos X e Y estão deslocados. Você precisa considerar esses deslocamentos. Além disso, minha resposta é sobre coordenadas de tela, mas seu gráfico usa coordenadas cartesianas. Me parece um problema mais complexo e totalmente diferente do que entendi da sua pergunta...

Comment: Certo, vou tentar criar as coordenadas cartesianas. Abrir um novo topico senão vir solução. Com esse exemplo como posso desactivar as linhas do rato ao sair do grafico?

Comment: @akm no `elemento.onmouseout` você pode escondê-las setando `style.display = 'none'` nos elementos que fazem as linhas (estou supondo que você esteja falando da minha outra resposta, que tem essas linhas...)

Comment: Sim é a outra pergunta do cursor, utilizei condição caso passa tal pixeis, fica escondida.